# Regular Expression in indexOf on javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, indexof

I want get my program parameters from rel attribute of  element, first of all is it logical ?

and the rel attribute may contain this string `rel="_p|b|w=300|h=200"` or `rel="_p|w=300"`
, so I use split to split my string with | pattern :

```
var attr = $(this).attr('rel').split('|');
```

for `_p` and `b` there is no problem because I can check with `indexOf` but for `w` and `h` I should use regular expression because the `w` and `h` value will be change.

how can I use regular expression in indexOf ?

sorry for my bad English

EDIT:

```
if (attr.indexOf('b')) {
        blank = true;
    }
```

Comment: Use custom data attributes, is `data-width="300" data-height="200"` not much better?

Comment: What are you using `indexOf` to do?  Check what?

Comment: @PaoloBergantino is it W3C valid ? I want to get w3c validation

Comment: @Rocket I edited my post, I want to check if _p and b is exists change another variables

Comment: @MajAfy: If you have an HTML5 doctype in your document it should validate. Either way I strongly encourage you not to pack all the data inside the rel attribute of your element. It is really not very elegant at all.

Comment: @MajAfy: It's valid with a `<!doctype html>`.

Comment: @Linus G Thiel: "Attribute cust-data not allowed on element div at this point." HTML5 selected

Comment: @Armatus: `cust-data`? What does that have to do with anything? It's obvious on SO that the people who need help the most are the least likely to get, and least likely to accept it... Well, good luck to the rest of you all.

Comment: @Armatus: It's `data-X` not `X-data`.

Comment: Instead of | separating them, I'd use a JSON and parse that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that isn't a very elegant way of retrieving data. Anyway, if you really want to do that in that way, then you can use regexes as follows:

```
var matches = $(this).attr('rel').match(/w=(\d+)/);
var w = (matches && matches[1]) || defaultValue;
```

Also, if there can be multiple elements that end in 'w', then you'd better change your regex to something like:

```
var matches = $(this).attr('rel').match(/(?:^|\|)w=(\d+)/);
```

Comment: thank you but as I said, in rel may be exists another parameters but the standard format for separation of parameters is `|` .

Comment: Can we please not do `$(this).attr('rel')`? If his markup is validating now, whatever element that is should have a `rel` property matching the attribute... `this.rel`!

Comment: I'm not focusing in how to retrieve the value of the attribute itself, but in the regex to capture the value of some data inside that attribute's value

Answer (score 0):

I would have suggested the use of custom attributes as well, however these would not be w3-conform as you want them to.

A simple way would be to split the parameters and then loop through and check each index whether it is one of the attributes you are expecting:

```
var cust_params = $(this).attr('rel').split('|'); //or this.rel as GGG suggested in a comment?

for(var i=0;i<cust_params.length;i++) {
    if('_p'==cust_params[i]) {
        //...
    }
    //...
    if(cust_params[i].match(/w=(\d+)/)) {
        //you could even do this without a regular expression
    }
}
```

I hope this doesn't violate some good practice that I'm unaware of because I always feel like there must be a more elegant way when I do this kind of thing :) As it is I get a kind of quick-and-dirty feel about this.

Comment: your solution is that I wanted, but you suggested I use custom attributes, but this is HTML5 , I want work XHTML, do you have other solution ?

Comment: I suggested to use custom attributes but as an alternative you can use the example I gave, which does not rely on custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Like Paolo Bergantino I'd also suggest using data-attributes, *or* you could store the data in a JSON (again, in a data attribute) and parse that:

```
<a href="#" data-info='{"width": "300", "height": "200", "color": "#fff", "etc": "foo"}'>

var info = JSON.parse(a.getAttribute('data-info'));
```

Edit: replaced `eval` with Phrogz's suggestion.

(With eval: `eval('(' + a.getAttribute('data-info') + ')')`)

Comment: While this is nicely more terse than using one data attribute per, er, attribute, I would suggest that it would be semantically better to store the information in the attributes instead of an alternate format. (I didn't -1 for this, however.) Note also that you have JS literals in there, but not JSON; you'd need formatting like `data-info='{"width":300,"height":200}'`

Comment: Please... Not eval. eval is evil.

Comment: I'd prepare for some -1 here :)

Comment: I know eval is frowned upon, but in this case what is the downside? I agree with Phrogz though.

Comment: Oh yeah, and there are much better ways to convert JSON into JavaScript objects, such as `JSON.parse(...)`.

Comment: Is that the correct usage of JSON.parse? And what's the browser support like?

Comment: `eval` is actually suggested here: http://www.json.org/js.html and as long as the source is safe I fail to see why it's so "evil". Ok, it may not be as fast as a proper parser but could someone explain what could go wrong here?

Comment: @powerbuoy This code not work ! JSON data should be in double-quotes and in single-quote the JSON.parse not work!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is no way you can do it in one command with normal javascript, indexOf just doesn't support regular expression.

You can either loop through the array or use `jquery` supported command for array.

For example: once you have the array `attr` as you like, you can use `jQuery.grep()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

```
a_equal = jQuery.grep(attr, function(a, i){
  return (a.match(/=/) and i > 0); // modify this as you like
});
```

to create an array `a_equal` with all the assignment argument.

*disclaimer.. code not yet tested.*